# az blob list: show only some properties

Tags: azure

I have a container on Azure and I want to see a list of all the blob I have in it.
If I type on my shell

```
az storage blob list --container-name MYCONTAINER --account-name MYSTORAGEACCOUNT
```

I get as an output a list of all my blobs like this:

```
 [
  {
    "content": null,
    "deleted": false,
    "metadata": null,
    "name": "myblobname.csv",
    "properties": {
      "appendBlobCommittedBlockCount": null,
      "blobTier": "Hot",
      "blobTierChangeTime": null,
      "blobTierInferred": true,
      "blobType": "BlockBlob",
      "contentLength": 275821,
      "contentRange": null,
      "contentSettings": {
        "cacheControl": null,
        "contentDisposition": null,
        "contentEncoding": null,
        "contentLanguage": null,
        "contentMd5": "YmQ+hefF/6IdNRv+GbD94A==",
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
      },
      "copy": {
        "completionTime": null,
        "id": null,
        "progress": null,
        "source": null,
        "status": null,
        "statusDescription": null
      },
      "creationTime": "2021-11-03T03:28:40+00:00",
      "deletedTime": null,
      "etag": "0x8D99E7A082AFA6A",
      "lastModified": "2021-11-03T03:28:40+00:00",
      "lease": {
        "duration": null,
        "state": "available",
        "status": "unlocked"
      },
      "pageBlobSequenceNumber": null,
      "remainingRetentionDays": null,
      "serverEncrypted": true
    },
    "snapshot": null
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

but, as an output, I only would like the name and properties.contentLength.

can anyone suggest me how should I edit my script in order to get only the params I want?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli).

> The Azure CLI uses the `--query` argument to execute a JMESPath query on the results of commands. JMESPath is a query language for JSON, giving you the ability to select and modify data from CLI output. Queries are executed on the JSON output before any display formatting.

In your specific case, try this:

`az storage blob list --container-name MYCONTAINER --account-name MYSTORAGEACCOUNT --query '[].properties.contentLength'`

In this query statement, you're parsing all of the entities in an array (your results), and accessing the contentLength under properties for each of the array items.

Comment: Or to get "the name and properties.contentLength" : `[].[name,properties.contentLength]`  or `[].{name:name,contentLength:properties.contentLength}` depending on the prefered output (list or dictionary).

Comment: When running on a Windows command line, I had to use double quote for the query argument to make this work, so for example "[].[name]" instead of '[].[name]' to get only the path names. Otherwise I get zero results.